# Jmeter with csv file in Linux for Login

Tags: linux, csv, file, jmeter

Iam new to linux , i know how to run jmx files with CSV in Windows. Can any please guide how to run the jmx script with CSV for concurrant logins ??

Comment: What isn't working? Show how you execute in windows and your try on linux

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the same way:

1. Use [relative path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html#relative) to the CSV file, not the absolute path because Linux file system is different, it doesn't have drive letters
2. Copy the CSV file along with the .jmx file to the same folder at the Linux machine, this way you will be able to use just filename in the CSV Data Set Config
3. If you need the guidance on [installation of JMeter on Linux](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans/):

   - you will need [Java Runtime Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), check you Linux distribution documentation for Java installation details
   - download JMeter using your browser (or command-line tools like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.se/))
   - copy the .jmx and the .csv files to the machine
   - run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

Comment: Can you please the send the command/syntax to run a csv file with jmx file in Linux